# Does the CPU usage retrieved from node.js os.cpus() in a docker container instance indicate host CPU or container CPU?

Tags: node.js, docker, cpu-usage

I'm using os.cpus() to monitor my node.js app in container instances, but wonder if the usage indicates the CPU of the instance or the docker host?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you showed your workings so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For docker containers, there isn't a hard distinction between CPU/mem inside or outside the container like there is virtual machines. Basically, all containers share the same kernel and there isn't a namespace for CPUs or Memory that causes the container to see those differently. Thus, `os.cpus()` shows the usage information of the host system including all workloads. To see usage information for your containers you can use the `docker stats` command on the host system. For Node.js, checkout the [systeminformation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation) package which also provides usage information for docker containers. However, this is only usable if run on the host (not inside a container)!

See also: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats/